# What is the difference between a probability mass function and a discrete distribution?

Tags: probability

I've heard the term PMF and discrete distribution used interchangeably. Does each term mean something different?

Comment: It's a good question (+1), but it seems to me it is clearly answered in the first paragraph of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function). What would you like us to add to or improve upon the information available there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two opinions, slightly depending on the field you are coming from. One is that they are exactly the same. Another is that the PMF is a description of the distribution, and the distribution is the "underlying phenomenon" being described (so even if you would describe it in some other way it would remain the same phenomenon).

Searching around a bit, I found both versions. The [Probability Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) Wikipedia page shortly mentions this under the Terminology section.